# Vectorizable FIND function with if statement MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have a matrix `u`, I want to go across all rows and all columns and do the following. If the element is non zero, I return the value of the row index. If the element is zero, find the row index the next non zero element after this element. I can do this easily using two for loops with a find function. But I need to do this many many times (not because of the size of the matrix but because this is called many times). How can I do it faster?

here is the for loop code:

```
     for w=scenario_size:-1:1
            for t=1:time_size
                l = u(t,w) ;
                if l~=0
                    tprime = t ;
                else
                    tprime = t+ find(u(t:end,w),1,'first') -1 ;
                end
                i(t,w)       = tprime ;
                boo(t,w)     = number(tprime,w)/u(tprime,w) ;
            end
end
```

Example if one column is `[0,0,5,1,0,3]`, the `i` is `[3,3,3,4,6,6]`. The last element of any column of `u` is always non-zero (I forced this by artificially adding a row of ones at the end).

Then `boo` is the corresponding entry to `tprime` for some matrix `number` divided by the corresponding `u` (which is non zero by construction).

Comment: Please define the inputs (`scenario_size` etc) so that the code can be run, and indicate what the desired output is

Comment: Also, provide a small example together with its expected output. Do I understand well that if one column is `[0,0,5,1,0,3]`, its expected output is `[3,3,3,4,6,6]`?

Comment: @LuisMendo you can take any input - the question is general. Say scenario_size = time_size = 3. Take any random u

Comment: Of course the question is general. But if you don't provide example input and output we cannot be sure that (1) we are running the code with the possible input restrictions you have in mind, and (2) we are producing the exact output that you want. For example (but do address my general points above), you say _If the element is zero, find the row index the next non zero element after this element_. What if there is no such element? I'm voting to close as unclear until the question is made clearer

Comment: @Florian you understand correct.There is one additional step required. I am updating the question with your example.

Comment: Explain what needs to happen if the last element of a column is zero.

Comment: @CrisLuengo i just edited again. The last element of any column of u is always non-zero (I forced this by artificially adding a row of ones at the end).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve this using [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html), [`cummin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cummin.html), and some [logical indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html#MatrixIndexingExample-3). Starting with this example case:

```
>> u = randi([0 1], 10);
>> u(end, :) = 1

u =

     0     0     0     0     1     0     1     0     1     1
     1     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     1
     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     1     1     0
     1     1     1     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     0     1     0     0     1     1     0     1
     1     1     0     1     0     1     1     1     1     1
     1     0     0     1     0     0     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

The following will do what you want:

```
i = nan(size(u));  % Start with all nan values
[r, ~] = find(u);  % Get row indices of non-zero values
i(u ~= 0) = r;     % Place row indices in locations of non-zero values
i = cummin(i, 1, 'reverse');  % Column-wise cumulative minimum, starting from bottom
```

And the result:

```
i =

     2     4     2     2     1     3     1     3     1     1
     2     4     2     2     2     3     7     3     3     2
     4     4     4     7     4     3     7     3     3     7
     4     4     4     7     4     4     7     7     5     7
     6     6     5     7    10     8     7     7     5     7
     6     6     6     7    10     8     7     7     8     7
     8     7    10     7    10     8     7     7     8     7
     8     8    10     8    10     8     8     8     8     8
     9    10    10     9    10    10     9     9     9     9
    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10
```

And you can then calculate your matrix `boo` by converting `i` to a [linear index](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html#MatrixIndexingExample-2):

```
index = i+time_size.*repmat(0:(scenario_size-1), time_size, 1);  % Create linear index
boo = number(index)./u(index);
```

Alternatively, you can compute `i` as a linear index from the start:

```
i = nan(size(u));  % Start with all nan values
index = find(u);   % Get linear indices of non-zero values
i(index) = index;  % Place linear indices in locations of non-zero values
i = cummin(i, 1, 'reverse');  % Column-wise cumulative minimum, starting from bottom
boo = number(i)./u(i);
```

Comment: Would this be faster than what I had? We both use the find function

Comment: @bissi: The above requires no loops. It's a single call to `find`, as opposed to multiple calls within your loops. I'd expect it should be faster, but you'd have to test it to be sure.

Comment: I confirmed that this works for the calculation of i. How would you the replace the last line of the loop: boo(t,w)     = number(tprime,w)/u(tprime,w) ;?
I have not yet checked for time

Comment: @bissi: I already added how to compute `boo` to the current answer.

Comment: This is an order faster than the multiple calls to find, on my data.

Comment: can we extend this to 3D arrays?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60799304/vectorizing-a-parallel-for-loop-across-multiple-dimensions-matlab?noredirect=1#comment107570995_60799304

Answer (score 1):

**@gnovice** answer is good, just to give an alternative to `find` function

- First the `u` matrix

```
    >> u = randi([0 1], 10);
    u(end, :) = 1;
    >> u

    u =

         0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0
         0     1     1     1     0     1     0     1     1     1
         1     1     1     0     1     0     0     1     1     0
         1     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     0     1
         1     1     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
         0     0     1     0     1     1     1     0     0     1
         0     1     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     1
         0     1     0     1     1     1     0     1     1     0
         0     0     0     1     0     1     1     1     1     1
         1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

- Then the `non-zeros` row indices can be computed as follow

```
    >> t = 1:10*10;% All elements indices
    r = t(u ~= 0); % All non-zeros elements indices 
    >> r

    r =

      Columns 1 through 18

         3     4     5    10    12    13    14    15    17    18    20    22    23    24    26    30    32    34

      Columns 19 through 36

        35    38    39    40    43    44    45    46    47    48    50    51    52    55    56    57    58    59

      Columns 37 through 54

        60    61    64    65    66    69    70    72    73    74    78    79    80    82    83    88    89    90

      Columns 55 through 60

        92    94    96    97    99   100
```

Comment: The previous answer was very fast - I have not tested your solution.

Comment: I would use `t = 1:numel(u)`, just to avoid magic numbers in the code. This is likely faster than `find`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo You're right, just wanted OP to see I am using the size of `u` and he seems not to be  interested in using built-in function

Comment: One small point: `r` will contain *linear* indices, not *row* indices. For row indices, you can change `t` to `t = repmat(1:size(u, 1), 1, size(u, 2));`

Comment: @Adam can you extend your logic to 3D arrays?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60799304/vectorizing-a-parallel-for-loop-across-multiple-dimensions-matlab?noredirect=1#comment107570995_60799304