# sub2ind multiple dimensions - element access

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a matrix of three dimensions, say `u`. I have another matrix of three dimensions, say `B`. Say the dimensions of `u` and `B` are `CxTxW`. For every element of `u`,  I wish to do the following: 
If `u` is >0, then report back both the value of `u` as well as the corresponding  `T` dimension it is in, and the corresponding element of  `B/u`. If the `u` is 0, then report back the next `T` (for the same `C`,`W`) with a positive `u` and the `T` and the corresponding `B/u` element. In the code below I call `B/u` as `benefit`.

The following linked question answers this in a very efficient manner for C=1 (i.e, two dimensions). I can write a for loop around the c and repeat the linked answer for every element of C but I wish to do it without the for loop.

[Vectorizable FIND function with if statement MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56363677/vectorizable-find-function-with-if-statement-matlab/56370830#56370830)

Here is the solution with a loop:

```
for c=1:C
    dummy_u = reshape(u(c,:,:),[T+1 W]) ;
    dummy_B = reshape(B(c,:,:),[T+1 W]) ;

    dummy_i = nan(size(dummy_u)) ;  % Start with all nan values
    [dum_row, ~] = find(dummy_u);  % Get row indices of non-zero values
    dummy_i(dummy_u ~= 0) = dum_row;     % Place row indices in locations of non-zero values
    dummy_i = cummin(dummy_i, 1, 'reverse');  % Column-wise cumulative minimum, starting from bottomi
    dum_i = dummy_i+(T+1).*repmat(0:(W-1), T+1, 1);  % Create linear index
    dummy_benefit = dummy_B(dum_i)./dummy_u(dum_i);
    i(c,:,:)       = dummy_i ;
    benefit(c,:,:) = dummy_benefit ;
    clear dum_i dum_row dummy_i dummy_benefit
end
```

How can I do it without a for loop?

Comment: can you clarify *"...as the value of the t and the corresponding B."*? you mean if say `u(n)` is >0 then you want to know which row in `T` it was and what was `B(n)`?

Comment: @bla exactly yes

Comment: I edited the question a bit to clarify what you ask, I think it will be beneficial to add the loop version code you have.

Comment: @bla I have added the loop

Comment: `reshape(u(c,:,:),[T+1 W])` in your code gives an error if `u` has size `C`x`T`x`W`. Ideally, provide a small example with inputs and desired output

Comment: I added an extra column for T+1 with all non-zeros to prevent the situation that all elements in a u row are zero. So u is effectively of size T+1

Comment: Don't you think that should have been stated in the question? In addition, `benefit` (which is presumably the output) doesn't contain elements of `B` or of `u`, as the question text suggests. Your question seems interesting, but is very unclear. Downvoting until resolved. As I said, example input and output would help clarify what you want

Comment: @LuisMendo see again

Comment: There's still the `T+1` problem. Your code won't run with the inputs you specify (`C`x`T`x`W`). And as I said (twice), example input and output would help clarify what you want. You can use small `C`, `T`, `W` for convenience

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reshaping one row into a `T x W` matrix, you can permute the whole thing into a `T x CW` matrix:

```matlab
>> C = 4; T = 5; W = 3;
>> u = reshape(1:C*T*W, C, T, W)   % generate sample u
u =

ans(:,:,1) =

    1    5    9   13   17
    2    6   10   14   18
    3    7   11   15   19
    4    8   12   16   20

ans(:,:,2) =

   21   25   29   33   37
   22   26   30   34   38
   23   27   31   35   39
   24   28   32   36   40

ans(:,:,3) =

   41   45   49   53   57
   42   46   50   54   58
   43   47   51   55   59
   44   48   52   56   60

>> du = reshape(permute(u, [2 1 3]), T, [])
du =

    1    2    3    4   21   22   23   24   41   42   43   44
    5    6    7    8   25   26   27   28   45   46   47   48
    9   10   11   12   29   30   31   32   49   50   51   52
   13   14   15   16   33   34   35   36   53   54   55   56
   17   18   19   20   37   38   39   40   57   58   59   60
```

The rest of your code should work unchanged (except for adding the dummy row) on `du`.

The inverse would be:

```matlab
>> permute(reshape(du, T, C, W), [2 1 3])
ans =

ans(:,:,1) =

    1    5    9   13   17
    2    6   10   14   18
    3    7   11   15   19
    4    8   12   16   20

ans(:,:,2) =

   21   25   29   33   37
   22   26   30   34   38
   23   27   31   35   39
   24   28   32   36   40

ans(:,:,3) =

   41   45   49   53   57
   42   46   50   54   58
   43   47   51   55   59
   44   48   52   56   60
```

I have no idea if this solution is actually faster.